# Simple Json log Parser Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

I had a coding assignment task(interview) for a senior data engineer role, JSON data validation. Every record in the input json indicates a customer record, I need to write a script to validate that all records confirms to few business rules and few more field type/length restrictions.

I used object-oriented, meta-data driven approach to write this parser in Python. However, I got negative feedback for the task and I am hoping to get some feedback on the code. Here is the git repo with some extra readme for the context and Business rules - https://github.com/YADAAB/jsonparser

I am looking for some inputs on coding style, overall design, object-oriented approach etc.

An example of email validation since the stackXchange wants me to add some code in the question :)

```
        email_regex = '^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$'
    try:
        if(re.search(email_regex,self.line_dict[field_name])):
            return True
        else:
            self.error_dict[field_name] = str(self.error_dict.get(field_name, '')) + 'Invalid email'
```

Would love to answer any specific questions. Thanks for checking!

Comment: bump here for any feedback